# Problem with Silverlight Media Player

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint, moss

**What I have?**

I have a web part which loads Silverlight object dynamically. The web part loads Media player and runs a video. I am referring to Silverlight 2.0.

Following code I am using:

```
Silverlight silverlightControl = new Silverlight();
silverlightControl.ID = "VideoXaml";
silverlightControl.Source = "~/_layouts/1033/MyVideoPlayer.xap";
silverlightControl.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
silverlightControl.Height = new Unit(400);
silverlightControl.InitParameters = paramBuilder.ToString();
silverlightControl.AutoUpgrade = true;

this.Controls.Add(silverlightControl);
```

**What I want to do?**

Now, I want to run the same code in Silverlight 3.0. So, I am packaging the the DLL, System.Web.Silverlight.dll with the web part and when this DLL is present in GAC, the web part works fine al least in my machine which has only Silverlight 3.0.

**What problem am I facing?**

On one of my client's machine with Silverlight 3.0, the web part does not works where as other Silverlight web part works fine.

We tired changing the code by loading the Silverlight object using JavaScript (Silverlight 3 way). But, then we faced problem in loading the Silverligh control when other web parts implementing call back on the same page. The Video web part shows the loading animation forever.

Has anyone faced problems like this and found any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a Microsoft product, what do you expect? :)

Comment: Not to start of flame war @zinc, but Linux's backward compatibility is it's Achilles heal, IMO. MS used to care deeply about that, I'm not so sure any more.

Answer (score -2):

Read the Microsoft Whitepaper about System.Web.Silverlight at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153377